# PHP Escaping single quote added by mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a product name and description with single quotes (Men's Shirt) and backslashes (shirt size M \ 38 ) into my table. Here is my code

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

// Usually I populate these values from POST

$s_no=1;
$prod_name = "Men's Shirt";
$prod_desc = "High quality Men's shirt size M \ 38";

$safe_prod_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$prod_name);
$safe_prod_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$prod_desc);

$insert = "INSERT INTO `test`(`s_no`, `product_name`, `product_desc`) VALUES (?,?,?);";
$query = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($query, $insert)) {
    header("Location: test.php?error=DBINSERTError");
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "iss",$s_no , $safe_prod_name, $safe_prod_desc);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
}

?>
```

After inserting, data in the table looks like this

```
+------+--------------+----------------------------------------+
| s_no | product_name |              product_desc              |
+------+--------------+----------------------------------------+
|    1 | Men\'s Shirt | High quality Men\'s shirt size M \\ 38 |
+------+--------------+----------------------------------------+
```

I saw many SO posts, and many suggest using **stripslashes()** and checking whether magicquotes are turned off. I have also added `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` in .htaccess file to ensure that. But still this backslash is getting inserted into the table. I cannot use stripslashes while retrieving because "**High quality Men's shirt size M \ 38**" will become "**High quality Men's shirt size M 38** ".

kindly suggest to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** use `mysqli_real_escape_string` in the first place.

Bound parameters **replace** escaping. They don't supplement it.

Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and then trying to undo its effects afterwards is just silly.